# Swift Segment Control how to select more than one segment

Tags: swift, select, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a Segment Control in my app, I want to user to be able to click multiple of the segments. I googled and could not find any about this and there was no checkbox in Xcode for something like 'Allow multiple selection'. I found that in objective-c you weren't able to do this, is this still the same for swift, and if so is there another thing that can do what I want to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UISegmentedControl)

> Content for each segment is set individually. Using the Segment field,
>   you can select a particular segment to modify its content.

So you can not choose multiple segments into Segmented Control.

For more information read that document.